# React Error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstarp/ListGroup'

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am learning React but getting some error when using bootstrap ListGroup. I have tried searching the same but could not understand the issue why this is happening and how to resolve it.

I have installed `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap` as per documentation. It's working fine with **form** but throwing error with **ListGroup**.

I have tried this as well `import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstarp';`

Can any one tell me why it is throwing this error.

[image]

**Product List Component:**

```
import React from 'react'
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstarp/ListGroup';

function ProductList() {

    return(
        <>
          <div className="list-container">
            <div className="header">
                <h3>Products</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel">
                <ListGroup>
                    <ListGroup.Item>Oppo F9 Pro</ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>Samsung Galaxy A1</ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>Lava Lite Pro</ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>Sony Xperia Lite</ListGroup.Item>
                    <ListGroup.Item>iPhone 13 Pro</ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

export default ProductList;

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
//Custom code
import ProductList from './components/ProductList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <ProductList/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Ref: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/list-group/

Comment: typo in line number 2 it should be `bootstrap` not `bootstarp`

Answer (score 0):

Module not found error occurs when you are using some module and that module is not installed or the node is unable to locate that module due to the wrong path.

**One module you are trying to install has either dependency on other modules as well**

so sometimes not all the modules are installed correctly due to some permission security issues.

So please try giving all permission or run as Root and add sudo if you are using an ubuntu machine.

So you can install that module by directly running the following command:-

```
npm install react-bootstrap-validation --save
```

or if you are using Linux/ubuntu then run the following command:-

```
sudo npm install react-bootstrap-validation --save
```

Or first please check in the console when installing the module that

is there any dependency error showing in the console

if so then please also attach that console, in that case, you need to install the dependent module also as separately via npm install.

**Hope this will help!**

**Thanks**